# How to import 3d texture in Unity?

Tags: unity, textures, voxels

How can I import a 3d texture the easisest way and visualize it somehow ( for example as a voxelized thing but other way can be also good)?

I tried to download a 3d texture form different sites like sketchfab.com or from unity assets store but I don’t really know which one is a 3d texture and how a 3d texture should look like.

In other words, how can I import a 3d texture and visualize it? Can I use a simple 2d texture?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think best would be to actually include what you have downloaded as a small image and what you expect it to look like. Voxel and a 3d texture are quite far from each other (or do you mean to generate a voxel world from a height map?)

Comment: As far as I know 3d texture in unity is an exclusive feature of the paid version. Even though there is no documentation or terms stating this. The personal version just gets the wrong rendering in black : (

Comment: [There are instructions for how to import and preview a ,3D texture in Unity in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Texture3D.html). Can you show us what specifically you tried, what results you got, and how that differs from what you want/expect?

Comment: "I don’t really know which one is a 3d texture and how a 3d texture should look like" this part starts to sound a little like an XY problem. Why are you looking into 3D textures at all if you don't know what they should look like? What application in your game are you thinking of using 3D textures to serve? Telling us more about that specific use case can help us tailor answers appropriate to that use, or steer you in a better direction if 3D textures aren't the right fit for what you have in mind.

Comment: Actually I would like to resize a 3d texture with a compute shader then visualize it in the scene. I recently read that there is no native 3d textures available to import into unity. It is created from 2d textures, for example in case of flipbooks.

Comment: Can you clarify how you've tried using the instructions from the docs I linked above? We can repeat what's already specified there, but if something in there isn't serving your needs, we need to know where you ran into trouble with it so we can tailor answers to help you with that specific issue.